# Google Sheet - Return unique id with maximum mark associated

Tags: google-sheets

Good day

I'm trying to return the maximum mark of each student. If the fails the training, they can try a new attempt, and my summary sheet should include only unique value with highest mark obtained.

Example of data:

```
| | A |B |
| -| - | - |
|1 |email | score|
|2|abc@mail.com | 1|
|3 |abd@mail.com | 3|
|4 |abc@mail.com | 3|
|5 |abc@mail.com | 4|
|6 |abe@mail.com | 5|
|7 |abe@mail.com | 4|
|8 |abe@mail.com | 7|
|9 |jvr@mail.com | 1|
|10 |jvr@mail.com | 7|
```

And i would like to return this table:

```
 | | D |E |
|- | - | - |
|1 |email | score|
|2| abc@mail.com | 4|
|3 |abd@mail.com | 3|
|4 |abe@mail.com | 7|
|5 |jvr@mail.com | 7|
```

```
Code used in COL D2: <br>
    =UNIQUE(A2:A,FALSE,FALSE)<br>
Code used in COL E2: <br>
    =if(G2<>"", ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(G2,D2:E,2,false)),"")<br>
Code used in COL E3: <br>
   =if(G3<>"", ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(G3,D3:E,2,false)),"")<br>
```

Is there any way to optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

In `D2` paste

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A)
```

[image]

In `E2` paste this formula

```
=MAX(TRANSPOSE(FILTER($B$2:$B, $A$2:$A=D2)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A2:B, 2, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

```
A2:B     range
2        sort by 2nd column
0        in descending order
9^9      return all rows
2        group by
1        first column
1        in ascending order
```